# Is file ready to read immediately after std::ofstream is destroyed?

Tags: c++, std, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

Basically I have following workflow (through console application):

- Read binary file (`std::ifstream::read`)
- Do something with data read
- Write back to same file    (`std::ofstream::write`), overwriting what
  was    there before.

Now, if I run this whole console program 1000 times through a shell script (always using same file), is it safe to assume that read operation will not conflict with previously run program trying to write to file? Or I need to wait between executions (how long???)? Can I reliably determine if file is ready?

I know it is not the best design, just want to know if that will work reliably (trying to quickly gather some statistics - inputs are different, but output file is always same - needs to be read, info needs to be processed, then it needs to be updated (at this point simply overwriting it) ).

**EDIT:**

It looks like the problem with output being wrong is not related to OS based on answers, the read/write I do looks like:

```
//read
    std::ifstream input(fname,std::ios_base::binary);
    while(input)
    {
        unsigned value;
        input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value),sizeof(unsigned));
        ....
    }
    input.close();
...

//write
    std::ofstream output(fname,std::ios_base::binary);
    for(std::map<unsigned,unsigned>::const_iterator iter =originalMap.begin();iter != originalMap.end();++iter)
    {
        unsigned temp = iter->first;
        output.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&temp),sizeof(unsigned));
        temp = iter->second;
        output.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&temp),sizeof(unsigned));
    }
```

Comment: Are the program instances running at the same time or sequentially?

Comment: @Matteo Italia - They are running sequentially, essentially, shell script runs same console app in a loop...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> They are running sequentially, essentially, shell script runs same console app in a loop...

Then, on any "normal" operating system, there should be no problem.

When the application terminates the streams are destroyed, so all the data that may be kept in cache by the C/C++ streams is written in the underlying OS streams, that are then closed.

Whether the OS does some more caching is irrelevant - caching done by the operating system is transparent to applications, so, as far as applications are concerned, the data is now written in the file. If it is actually written on disk is of no concern here - the applications reading from the file will see the data in it anyway.

If you think about it, without such a guarantee it would be complicated to do reliably any work on a computer! :)

---

Update:

> ```
> std::ofstream output(fname,std::ios_base::binary);
> ```

You should truncate the output file before writing on it, otherwise, if the input file was longer than the output, old data will still be lingering at the end of the file:

```
std::ofstream output(fname,std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::trunc);
```

Comment: The problem is, I'm not getting proper output - at the end file has some meaningless data..

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy: then probably you have some other problem in your code. Are you truncating the file before writing on it? If not (=you are just doing an `seek` to the beginning and then a `write`) then the data at the end is probably a residue of the input file.

Answer (score 0):

Check parameters of the `fstream` ctor. Some implementations have extension, that allows conveniently set set sharing modes.

If you ask exclusive read or write, that's what you get as long as you keep the stream open -- other similar operations can not happen either from different processes or the same with a different stream instance.

With pure standard it requires more hops, probably setting them in filebuf and replace the stock one. Look after it.

Use of sharing modes is the mainstream way to defend file consistency, so I suggest to use it in any case.

Certainly if you make sure that race conditions are handled, one process will not open the file before the other closed it, the result is good that way too.

Comment: The problem with that is that I read it from different process (after previous console app that was writing to it has exited)... So, I know writing stream is destroyed, but, does it mean I can read from disk immediately after?

Comment: use read+deny_write on the reader part, if you can open with that the file content is surely final. On writer best to create fresh vile with write+deny_all. In make the reader open only existing file, then all is dandy.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: you seem right I was reading http://www.gamedev.net/topic/93785-sharing-file-w-fstream/ there must be a longer way then, fiddling with filebuf.

Comment: @BalogPal: probably it's just a non-standard extension.